# How to create files at runtime on python app-engine: live or localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine, filesystems, localhost

The question is simply as stated in the title. But the reason is probably important for a good answer.

I need to generate static html files at runtime. Generating the files is not the problem. Using `jinja2` and `webapp2` I can painlessly generate dynamic html files at runtime and serve them to my users. My problem is that generating these files is expensive. So I want to be able to save them as static html files; so that, when user tries to access them, I just serve the static html if it exists. If it does not exist, then I can create the file and then serve it.

Again I am already using `jinja2` to create my string (i.e. file content). So my question is, how do I save the file to a path that my `app.yaml` file can map to?

Also if you are thinking `memcache` I am already using that. It is not sufficient storage. So while it’s a buffer, it’s not as good as having static html files.

Some back story:

If I can generate the files in localhost, that'd be even better. The thing is the site has a huge number of pages. But the structure is common to all the pages. So we store the relevant data in the `datastore` and use `jinja2` to inflate the different pages. But because of heavy usage, memcache is not able to keep up. So now it's looking more cost-effective to create static html pages from the data stored in the `datastore`. Creating those pages by hand is obscene and error prone. So if we could generate the html pages as usual (i.e. `jinja2` template and datastore) and then have an automated system for creating the html pages, it would be awesome. We could do the `app.yaml` part manually.

So after I do

```
template = jinja_environment.get_template(‘template.html')
content = template.render(template_values)
```

What do I do to save the file to say `./relevant/path/filename.html`

Comment: Generate them locally.  Then upload as static html. There are a few different approaches you could take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write to files in App Engine -- see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/java?csw=1#writefile for explanation.

Why don't you store the post-rendered page content back in datastore? I'm assuming the "expensive" part of the approach you're using now is the building of the templated content from the data. Once you've done that, instead of writing it off to local files, you could either put it as an additional property on the original data entity or you could create an entirely new model just for the rendered pages.

Essentially this would be a durable datastore implementation instead of memcache, if the issue is that pages are getting evicted too often from memcache.

A single fetch (directly from the key, since you can use keynames that you can create based on the page you're fetching, so you don't have to even do a query) is lightweight. Then, if you're still using memcache, then you'd check memcache first; if not there, you fetch the entity from the datastore and check to see if the rendered property contains data. If not, you use the data in the entity to render it with Jinja, store it back off in the rendered property, put the entity, store it off in memcache, and return the rendered content back to the client.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good idea. But the reason I rejected it before is the involvement of the datastore. I always understood that static files are a lot cheaper than datastore access; even key-based access. By expensive I mean $$ money. Would key-based access be that much cheaper? I will look at pricing again. Thanks.

Comment: Also right now I am using an auto-generated id. Can I change it to a name for an existing entity without losing any data? I don't recall.

Comment: Yes, static files are cheap, but cannot be programmatically created/edited -- so that's unfortunately not viable. Do you know what type of miss rate you are getting on memcache? Any idea how many misses are as a result of eviction vs. not having been rendered yet? If you get 80+% hit rate on memcache, then 80+% hit rate on a rendered datastore entity, then you're only left with < 4% causing a full page generation. Depending on page size and how often data changes, you could also explore GCS, but probably not substantially different.

Comment: Given your IDs, probably use separate "rendered pages" entity/model vs. adding property to existing data entity. Implement a new entity that uses key names based on the page id/url and has only one property -- the rendered page text. It's only purpose is the be durable vs. memcache. Page request comes in, check memcache. If hit, return from memcache. If miss, get_or_insert() it with keyname. If that hits (has rendered_page prop), stuff in memcache and return page to user. If miss, full query/build, update and put() the rendered page to your get_or_insert(), update memcache, and return page.

Answer (score 2):

IfI understand your question properly, the best way to do this would be to store your static files in Google Cloud Storage (GCS).  Easy to read and write to GCS. And easy to delete the file when you no longer need it.